# An example of MemberTypes.Custom and MemberTypes.TypeInfo member

Tags: .net, reflection, types

There are eight different enumerated values for System.Reflection.MemberTypes. Five map directly to specific MemberInfo classes (ConstructorInfo, MemberInfo, etc.). The MemberTypes.NestedType can be thought of as Type rather than a MemberInfo. I'm trying to get my head around (1) MemberTypes.Custom and (2) MemberTypes.TypeInfo members. Does anyone have an example of such members?

Comment: For TypeInfo - did you realise that `System.Type : System.Reflection.MemberInfo` ?

Answer (score 6):

```
public class Foo
{
   public class Bar { }
}
```

With these two classes the following will be true.

```
typeof(Foo).MemberType == MemberTypes.TypeInfo
typeof(Foo.Bar).MemberType == MemberTypes.NestedType
```

Both `TypeInfo` and `NestedType` indicate that you are dealing with a type with the distinction whether the type is nested or not. The enumeration value `TypeInfo` just sticks with the naming convention while the actual subtype of `MemberInfo` is `Type`. On the one hand `Type` should have been called `TypeInfo` to stick with the naming convention, on the other hand it seems a bit questionable that `Type` is derived from `MemberInfo` in the first place. But that is just the way it is. Maybe member in `MemberInfo` should be better understood as assembly or type member instead of just type member.

Since .NET 4.5 there is new subclass [`TypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.aspx) inheriting from `Type` and accessible using the [`Type.GetTypeInfo()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo.aspx); see there for the distinction.

I am not sure about `MemberTypes.Custom` but looking at [CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), especially II.10.2, it may be the case that this refers to custom attributes or other custom data associated with a type. Looking at the [.NET reference source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) does not provide additional insight either.